# Angular-UI jQuery Passthrough vs angular.element()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

What is the provided functionality of Angular-UI Jquery Passthrough and angular.element()?

Are they interchangeable? does jQuery passthrough any additional options over angular.element()?

Any good examples out there that might demonstrate the power of each in an ng-app?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 2 unrelated pieces of code.

Passthru is just a simple wrapper that enables you to call any jQuery method on a DOM element without creating a new directive.

`angular.element()` is a javascript method that returns a DOM element. If you injected jQuery first then `angular.element() === jQuery() ==== $()`

Passthru does not do anything special, and `angular.element()` isn't needed because a `$element` is already provided by the linking function.